# List and draw partitions of an interval in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could one write a file (program) to draw (possibly in TikZ) all the partitions of the interval [0, 18] in 6 intervals of size = 1 and 6 of size = 2?

Observe that the partitions are in one-to-one relation with the numbers made up by two algarism (1 and 2 only) whose smallest one is:

```
111111222222
```

and the last one

```
222222111111
```

with quite a few in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can do a simple double recursion to generate the lists of 1 and 2's then iterate over each item in that list to draw lines 1 or 2 units apart to show the partitions

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\z#1#2#3{%
\ifnum#2>0
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\z{#11}{\the\numexpr#2-1\relax}{#3}}\tmp\par
\fi
\ifnum#3>0
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\z{#12}{#2}{\the\numexpr#3-1\relax}}\tmp\par
\else
\ifnum#2=0
#1 \quad \p{#1}\par
\fi
\fi
}
\newcount\zcount
\def\p#1{%
\begin{picture}(180,10)
\global\zcount=0
\multiput(0,-5)(10,0){19}{\makebox(0,0){\tiny\the\zcount}\global\advance\zcount1 }
\global\zcount=0
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){10}}
\zrules#10
\end{picture}}

\def\zrules#1{%
\ifnum#1=0
\else
\global\advance\zcount\numexpr10*#1\relax
\put(\zcount,0){\line(0,1){10}}%
\expandafter\zrules
\fi}

\parskip=20pt
\begin{document}

\z{}66

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get an error when running this by latex. ``! Undefined control sequence.
\z #1#2#3->\ifnum #2>0 \expanded 
                                 {\noexpand \z {#11}{\the \numexpr #2-1\rela...
l.36 \z{}66
``

Comment: @TeXApprentice ah you have an old version of pdftex without `\expanded` you can use lualatex which has always had this but I'll post a version without using that: it isn't essential here just simplified the code a bit

Comment: @TeXApprentice version with `\edef` instead of `\expandafter` posted.